# Prime knot in a solid torus

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K \subset V$ where $V$ is a standardly embedded solid torus in $S^3$.  Suppose every meridian disk of $V$ intersects $K$ at least twice.

If $K$ is prime in $S^3$ and $\Sigma \subset V$ is a 2-sphere intersecting $K$ in two points, must $\Sigma$ bound a trivial arc of $K$ on the inside (the component of $S^3 - \Sigma$ lying entirely within $V$)?

If we remove the condition that every meridian disk of $V$ intersects $K$ at least twice, this isn't true - for example if some meridian disk intersects $K$ once then compressing $\partial V$ along that disk and pushing slightly to the interior of $V$ gives a 2-sphere intersecting $K$ but that has the trivial arc on the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $K$ is prime, and consider the following picture:

[image: a knot in a torus with a sphere not containing a trivial arc]

$K$ is an associated $2$-tangle in the picture, and, modifying your example, instead of closing $K$ using a once-around arc, we use a twice-around arc.  The green sphere is $\Sigma$, and it contains $K$ rather than the trivial arc.

We know this knot intersects every meridian disk at least twice for homological reasons.

---

Every such sphere $\Sigma$ corresponds to a torus $T\subset V$ by attaching the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $K$ outside of $\Sigma$.  In particular, this $T$ has the property that there exists a meridian disk inside $T$ that intersects $K$ exactly once.  Conversely, any such $T$ gives a sphere by compressing along this disk.

The condition you want is that every essential torus $T$ in $V-K$ having a meridian disk inside $T$ intersecting $K$ in exactly one point is actually the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $K$.  Then every such $\Sigma$ contains a trivial arc.

Comment: I added a different version of the condition on the decomposition sphere in terms of tori inside of $V$.